# Array with empty values need to be discarded

Tags: php, arrays

Given, In a input form user can separate some specific names by new line and i am saving those names in an array. Then I print those names and at last say something like "thank you for the names".

```
         $var = "name1 



name2


        ";
    $your_array = explode("\n", $var);


        for($i=0; $i<(sizeof($your_array));$i++) {
          echo ($your_array[$i]);  
        }
echo "Thank you for the names"
```

But the problem is if someone enter more than one newline before or after a name then the next name show after some distance like below

```
    name1



    name2


Thank you for the names
```

How can escape this and output as below

```
name1
name2
Thank you for the names
```

I tried to use array_filter() but it don't work here.

**Update:**

```
If someone input
$var = "name1\nname2\n\n\n


           name3                     


name4";
```

output should be like

```
name1
name2
               name3
name4
```

But all the answers show like

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

Comment: just check if user give a newline in his input. If so just do not store it into the Array! Alternately, before printing you can check the same...

Comment: give like `$your_array = array_filter($your_array);`

Comment: User have to give newline to separate names. But if user give more than one new line after each name or give a new line then some space that causes the problem. I can not figure it out how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a foreach loop for the sake of simplicity...

1) We need to iterate through the new array and `trim` the names so we lose all whitespace.

2) We echo out the name, if and only if the length of the name is 1 or more.

3) We add on a `<br>` tag to make each name appear on a new line.

```
<?php

$var = "name1\nname2\n\n\n";

$your_array = explode("\n", $var);

foreach($your_array as $name)
{
    if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}/i", $name)) {
        $name = trim($name);
        echo (strlen($name) > 1) ? sprintf('%s<br>', $name) : '';
    }
}

echo "Thank you for the names";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i still got a small problem. See my updated question.

Comment: @AshiqurRahman Remove the `trim()` function if you want to keep whitespace.

Comment: In that case, if someone give only space in a line then it will also show but I have to check that each array contains at least one character and i think i should check it with regx

Comment: @AshiqurRahman Okay, check out the regex added to ensure there is a name inside the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
$your_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $var);

$names = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($your_array); $i ++ )
{
    // trim clean spaces and newlines surrounding each line
    // resulting value is assigned to $test
    // if this value is not empty the conditional is a true proposition
    // so is assigned to $names
    if ($test    = trim($your_array[$i]))
        $names[] = $test;
}

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $names) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Thank you for the names.';
```

**EDIT**: using `foreach`

```
$your_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $var);

foreach ($your_array as $name)
{
    if ($test    = trim($name))
        $names[] = $test;
}

if ($names)
{
    // echo implode(PHP_EOL, $names) . PHP_EOL;
    echo implode('<br />', $names) . '<br />';
    echo 'Thank you for the names.';
}
else
    echo 'Names missing.';
```

**EDIT 2**

`trim` accept a charlist to explicit removes, so if you want maintain spaces, make a list with `newlines` and `carriage return` only.

```
trim($name, "\r\n");
```

---

NOTE: PHP_EOL is the correct new line char depending of server (unix or windows).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i still got a small problem. See my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

[Be a better PHP developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/) and use native PHP array functions:

```
$raw_arr = array('    trim  ', 'fine', '    ');

array_walk($raw_arr, function(&$value) {
  $value = trim($value);
});

$reduced_arr = array_filter($raw_arr);

print_r($reduced_arr);
```

**Note:** I have used a closure. If you are running PHP < 5.3, you'll need to move this to a UDF.

#### UPDATE

Seems like you don't wish to trim the user input. As such, you can drop `array_walk` and its closure.

```
$raw_arr = array('    trim  ', 'fine', '');
$reduced_arr = array_filter($raw_arr);

print_r($reduced_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i still got a small problem. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i<(sizeof($your_array));$i++) {
    if (empty($your_array[$i])) continue;
          echo ($your_array[$i]);  
        }
echo "Thank you for the names"
```

Comment: You don't account for trimming the spaces. You also have an [unoptimized for loop](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/12/php-micro-optimizations/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i still got a small problem. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` + `array_map` + `trim` to discard empty space

```
$var = "name1 



name2


        ";

$array = array_filter(array_map("trim",explode("\n", $var)));
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $array) , PHP_EOL;
echo "Thank you for the names";
```

Or just use  `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all("/\S?([a-z0-9]+)\S?/", $var,$array);
echo implode(PHP_EOL, $array[0]),PHP_EOL;
echo "Thank you for the names";
```

Both Would Output

```
name1
name2
Thank you for the names
```